# Dúvidas com Entity Framework (Propriedades de Navegação e método Create)

Tags: entity-framework

Venho lendo vários artigos e até o momento não consegui entender a real função da propriedade de navegação. Nos últimos artigos que li, dizia que serve como chave estrangeira para navegação, porém, quando tentei criar um projeto iniciando pelo Modelo Primeiro (Model First), as chaves estrangeiras não ficaram com o mesmo nome das propridades de navegação. Outra dúvida é referente ao método Create, ao meu ver, este método teria a função de criar as entidades caso elas não existam no banco de dados, mas quando tentei excluir uma das entidades e testar o código, isso não aconteceu. Alguém poderia esclarecer essas duas dúvidas que ainda tenho? Segue o código com o método Create abaixo:

```
using (var db = new AccountingSystemContainer())
{
    var invHeader = db.InvoiceHeaderSet.**Create();**
    var invDetail = db.InvoiceDetailSet.**Create();**

    invHeader.Total = 150m;

    invDetail.ItemDescription = "Algum Item";
    invDetail.Price = 75m;
    invDetail.Quantity = 2;

    invHeader.InvoiceDetail.Add(invDetail);

    db.InvoiceHeaderSet.Add(invHeader);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Venho lendo vários artigos e até o momento não consegui entender a real função da propriedade de navegação.

São duas as funções das propriedades de navegação:

- Indicar ao Entity Framework uma relacionamento entre entidades;
- Fazer com que o Entity Framework preencha automaticamente dados de uma (ou mais) entidades relacionadas.

Por exemplo, suponha o seguinte:

```
public class Produto {
    [Key]
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public int Categoria Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
}
```

Eu poderia fazer este relacionamento assim:

```
public class Produto 
{
    [Key]
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }

    public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
}
```

O Entity Framework mapearia `Categoria` com `Produto` da mesma forma. O que muda é que o Entity Framework escolhe como a chave estrangeira vai se chamar, e que ela não é exatamente acessível dentro da aplicação, o que pode ser sim um problema, dependendo de como o sistema é desenvolvido.

#### Nos últimos artigos que li, dizia que serve como chave estrangeira para navegação, porém, quando tentei criar um projeto iniciando pelo Modelo Primeiro (Model First), as chaves estrangeiras não ficaram com o mesmo nome das propriedades de navegação.

Sim, isto não é garantido justamente porque você pode ter definido as entidades sem especificar o nome das chaves.

### Outra dúvida é referente ao método Create, ao meu ver, este método teria a função de criar as entidades caso elas não existam no banco de dados, mas quando tentei excluir uma das entidades e testar o código, isso não aconteceu.

Não é bem assim que [`Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679504(v=vs.113).aspx) funciona. Segundo a documentação:

```
    // Summary:
    //     Creates a new instance of an entity for the type of this set.  Note that
    //     this instance is NOT added or attached to the set.  The instance returned
    //     will be a proxy if the underlying context is configured to create proxies
    //     and the entity type meets the requirements for creating a proxy.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The entity instance, which may be a proxy.
```

Ou seja, a instância criada não está necessariamente adicionada (*added*) ou anexada (*attached*) ao contexto.

Quanto à parte de exclusão, preciso do código usado para executar a exclusão para que eu possa melhorar a resposta.

Comment: @KellySoares, te aconselho a procurar a diferença entre `new Entity()` vs `DbSet<Entity>.Create()`, eu particulamente só uso o `DbSet<Entity>.Create()` quando preciso carregar alguma propriedade  de navegação pelo LazyLoad.

Comment: Toby, obrigada pela sugestão, vou procurar sobre o assunto. Cigano, vou abrir uma nova pergunta e postar o código para você me explicar a exclusão e o funcionamento da propriedade de navegação nele, porque no modelo criado ele pega o nome de um campo e determina como chave estrangeira sem usar o nome da propriedade de navegação.